My app does not show the google map data in the app but shows all the other options like button
I want to show the light pollution webiste as a webview in Kotlin android app. But the webview is showing all the buttons and additional items but now showing the map.the Map has different light variation in different places which is not showing in app.
Website link:https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/#zoom=1.65&lat=14.7492&lon=-37.2076&state=eyJiYXNlbWFwIjoiTGF5ZXJCaW5nUm9hZCIsIm92ZXJsYXkiOiJ3YV8yMDE1Iiwib3ZlcmxheWNvbG9yIjpmYWxzZSwib3ZlcmxheW9wYWNpdHkiOjYwLCJmZWF0dXJlc29wYWNpdHkiOjg1fQ==
I am expecting to see the map with the different light variation in different places in the map.The android app doesnot show it but works perfectly like working of webview. I suspect it is due to the type of data in website it has different light variation in website
Logcat :
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null
at init (https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lightpollutionmap.js:28:351)
at HTMLDocument. (https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lightpollutionmap.js:19:35)
at e (https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30005)
at t (https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30307) undefined", source: https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js (2)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js (2)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(407)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lightpollutionmap.js (407)
D/ProfileInstaller: Installing profile for com.example.lightpollution
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(400)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/lightpollutionmap.js (400)

There are some configurable extra options for the Android WebView. You'd start with WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); and then set things like webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);, webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);, webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true); and others that might affect that specific website: WebSettings

Thank you using webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);   worked for me
